# Frontend UI Development

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I have jQuery based theme with below project structure, but I do not understand which tool is used to create this folder structure. I work with Angular2 but this folder structure is different. Can someone please advise how to create a new project with below structure

```
app
   js
   sass
   bower.json
   gulpfile.js
   package.json
   server.js
   vendor.json
   webpack.config.js
dist
   assets
   *.html files
```

Comment: This looks like something custom-made by hand, instead of any project templates I'm aware of.

Comment: Seems app is a development folder for developer. When compiled dist folder will be created generating the files to be deployed in production. app folder does not have any html files, it has js and scss files